# Django: How to use ModelForm and Generic Views

Tags: python, django, model, view

I am learning `Django`.

I got little confuse about uses of `Model Form` and `Generic Views`.

Though both are different but what i understood is both can generate `form` according to given `model class`

I have a different tables to store ideas, likes, comments and tags.

Whether I should use `model form` or `generic views` to get ideas from user and likes and comments.

I also want to customise layout of my forms, so what will be a better way for me?

I would like to understand how to use this features of `django`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generic views and model forms are not exclusive concepts; generic views are made to encompass the business logic of a particular function, while ModelForms create a form, validation/data cleaning logic, and CRUD functionality from the model's logic.

With the example below (from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview)), the UpdateView (a generic view provided as part of Django) creates a model form from a single model instance. Through CBV conventions, the primary key of the instance to be updated is expected as the first positional argument provided by the url.

In this case, a ModelForm is automatically generated. When more fine-grained control is needed, you can define your own ModelForm and provide it to the CBV. Hopefully this helps clear up your confusion.

Example myapp/views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from myapp.models import Author
from django import forms


class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name', 'city', ...]


class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Author
    form = MyModelForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

Example myapp/author_update_form.html:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Example myapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from myapp.views import AuthorUpdate

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^update_author/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)$', AuthorUpdate.as_view(), name='update_author'),
)
```

Comment: Thank you. So we can pass model forms to generic views.

Comment: how to customize fields layout in templates? Like custom styling.

Comment: See the update for passing custom ModelForms to a CBV. 

Customize fields through the Django template language. That's a big topic, there's a lot of good tutorials out there though! Loop through the fields for a form {% for field in form %}<div class='something'>{{ field }}</div>{% endfor %}  or call by name {{ form.author }} for a single field from the form.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated.